# .htaccess redirect but exclude some folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

Hello there I am using cpanel. In the cpanel, I created a redirect, which created an .htaccess like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteOptions inherit
Options -Indexes

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^paw\.xevz\.migor\.eu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.paw\.xevz\.migor\.eu$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/paw\.xevz\.migor\.eu\/mainfolder" [R=301,L]
```

The problem with this, when I added new folder my public directory and view my page, it will always redirect to the 'mainfolder'. How will I add a RewriteCond that will not redirect to the main folder if my link is something like http://paw.xevz.migor.eu/subfolder ? I tried like this,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^paw\.xevz\.migor\.eu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.paw\.xevz\.migor\.eu$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/paw\.xevz\.migor\.eu\/mainfolder" [R=301,L]
```

but no luck. Please help thank you.

P.S. Those links in my .htaccess are just sample.

Comment: There has to be a blank between `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `!^/subfolder/`...

Comment: @arkascha sorry my fault. I've updated my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^/?$` will only match and redirect landing page URI. You may have a front controller rule in the end that rewrites everything to something like `?page=something` and that would trigger this redirect rule for all the URIs that are not for a file or directory.

You may use this redirect rule instead:

```sh
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?paw\.xevz\.migor\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /mainfolder/ [R=302,L]
```

Make sure this is your topmost rules below `RewriteEngine On` line and you test it after clearing your browser cache.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` will make sure this rule is not executed after 1 or more rewrites due to other rules.

Comment: Thanks mate. I think I have a problem aside from this. I will set this as the correct answer. I have added a new question hope you can share your understanding about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654619/htaccess-causes-redirection . thanks